# Why the Interaction potentials parametrisations for Bulk system is not working for Nano-systems?

Tags: material-science, computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

I am studying several thermodynamics properties of crystalline iron oxides (Fe3O4, Gamma- Fe2O3) in their solid phases by MD simulations. At the moment, I am facing many difficulties in simulating the nano particles.
The crystal structures, I am using, are coming from [first principle simulations](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/22/25/255401) and interaction potentials parametrisations (Buckingham potential for short range and Coulombic potentials for Long range) developed for bulk iron oxides. Clearly the modelling is properly working for bulk iron oxides. Instead, when applied to nano-particles, the nano-particles become amorphous at any temperature.

In my opinion, the lack of Coulombic contribution in the nano-system (for bulk the contribution is large as the simulation box is periodic in each dimension) is causing this behavior.

Has anyone ever faced such issue while studying crystalline nano-structures?

Comment: Your question may get more attention at the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/#)

Comment: Thanks. I have posted there as well.